# How to build a two column fluid layout with Twitter Bootstrap v3.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Since bootstrap removed the *fluid css classes in v3.0, I couldn't find a way to build a two-column fluid layout. The goal is to achieve a layout similar to the Fluid Layout example in their old documantation:
 http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The grid in Bootstrap 3 is now fluid by default (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration-dropped). You just need to use `.row` and `.container`..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Sidebar content
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            Body content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This however will not be 100% width. If you want 100% width you can do something like this.. http://www.bootply.com/86324

**UPDATE:** 3.0.1 and later use `container-fluid` for full width.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the correct terms, I need the two columns to fill the entire height of the page, even when their content takes only a portion. am I clear?

Comment: The Bootstrap grid only affects width. Height is another issue. You can do something like this: http://bootply.com/86329