# Bootstrap Columns width and placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249811/how-to-build-a-two-column-fluid-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap-v3-0) post and it is working slightly how I want it to work BUT I want the placement of the second lot of text to be in the middle of the page.

This is my current result. I want Tuesday to be in the middle of the page.
[my current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXLrV.jpg)

Comment: To divide the content use `col-md-6` classes, for example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community. Please include a [mcve] to your question. Links can be unavailable at any given time making the question
incomplete and thus, impossible to answer

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to answer your question without your actual markup. If you're merely attempting to achieve a responsive layout, I would refer to the official [Bootstrap Examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples).

If you'd like to edit your question to include your HTML, I'm happy to provide a little more feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good reference site for Bootstrap columns:

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--- Content --->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--- Content --->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--- Content --->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should try col-md-4 and col-md-8 classes for your problem. May be this will help you. And Better way is that if you provide your html code then i can edit that code and can give you a exact answere.

Comment: Thanks. I will in future